# How to specify different screen session name during ssh

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I have multiple screen sessions running on one of my server (say `session_read`, `session_prod`..)

Currently I specify the screen session after I have sshed into my server.

Is there a way to specify the screen session while I am trying to ssh in?

Something like

```
ssh user@servername screen_session_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate a TTY, or SSH will complain:

```
$ ssh host screen
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

Assuming the session is already disconnected:

```
$ ssh -t user@host screen -r session
```

otherwise a suitable combination of -d, -r, -D, -R, -x per [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).

Answer (score 1):

I use a custom `hardstatus` line in `~/.screenrc`:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{wk}%-w%{Gk}[%n %t]%{wk}%+w%=%{Ck}%d %M %Y %c:%s"
```

combined with a little shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
show_help() {
  printf "Usage: con hostname\n"
  exit 0
}

[[ "$#" -eq 1 ]] || show_help

uppercase="${1^^}"
lowercase="${1,,}"

screen -t "${uppercase}" -T screen-256color ssh "${lowercase}"

exit 0
```

Put it somewhere in your PATH, and you only need to call it:

```
$ my_script hostname
```

and a new screen session will be allocated with the title set to the hostname you are connecting to.

You can provide further customizations via `~/.ssh/config` settings.